# How to say "I added" (editing a document)

Tags: single-word-requests

How would I say "I added ..." in Esperanto, in the context of editing a document? For example, "I added a picture of..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with other answers that *aldoni* is the appropriate word for this context, as well as in general context when you want to translate *add*.

Regarding edition in general, you can use *redakti* to translate *edit*, when your modification might just as well change and remove text, pictures, and so on in the document.

When you add (attach) a document to an email, you might prefer *kunligi*. For use cases involving a more intricate link, you could even use *alligi*.

More broadly, you might create words from whatever context suitable verb carrying the idea of a relation, prefixed with *kun-* or *al-*, depending on what you want mean precisely. Some roots which come to my mind are *glui, meti, kroĉi*.

In arithmetic, you might prefer *adicii* aŭ *plusi*.

Answer (score 5):

PIV: [*aldoni*](http://vortaro.net/#aldoni)

> *Mi aldonis bildon de… [mia kato]… al la dosiero.*

Answer (score 3):

I think "Mi aldonis..." is what you are looking for.

These examples from PIV are from other situations, but I think *aldoni* here can be properly comprehended as "add". 
- aldonu nenion al via respondo
- aldoni iom da acido al la miksaĵo